# Return multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have this part of a code:

```
def readTXT():
    part_result = []
    '''Reading all data from text file'''
    with open('dataset/sometext.txt', 'r') as txt:
        for lines in txt:
            part = lines.split()
            part_result = [int(i) for i in part]
            #sorted([(p[0], p[14]) for p in part_result], key=lambda x: x[1])
            print(part_result)
            return part_result
```

And I'm trying to get all lists as a return, but for now I'll get only the first one, what is quite obvious, because my `return` is inside the for loop. But still, shouldn't the loop go through every line and return the corresponding list?

After doing research, all I found was `return list1, list2` etc. But have should I manage it, if my lists will be generated from a text file line by line?

It frustates me, not being able to return multiple lists at once.

Comment: `return` immediately exists the execution of the function. All Python functions can return exactly *one* object. Note, `list1, list2` is actually a *tuple-literal*, it is the commas that make the tuple, not the parentheses! So, usually, the strategy is to accumulate all the values you want to return in some *other* data-structure (e.g. a list) and return that. Alternatively, you could use a *generator* which usees `yield` instead of return, and this will have semantics close to what you want, however, it creates a generator (a type of iterator) and is a bit more advanced

Comment: You might want to look into `yield`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my suggestion. Creating a 'major_array' and adding 'part_result' in that array on each iteration of loop. This way if your loop iterates 10 times, you will then have 10 arrays added in your 'major_array'. And finally the array is returned when the for loop finishes. :)

```
def readTXT():
    #create a new array
    major_array = [] 
    part_result = []
    '''Reading all data from text file'''
    with open('dataset/sometext.txt', 'r') as txt:
        for lines in txt:
            part = lines.split()
            part_result = [int(i) for i in part]
            #sorted([(p[0], p[14]) for p in part_result], key=lambda x: x[1])
            print(part_result)
            major_array.append(part_result)
         return major_array
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: Don't beg for upvotes.  If it's a good answer, it'll be upvoted without needing to ask for them.  Also, I'd suggest not saying that an answer is simple.  To someone learning the basics, it doesn't feel simple and saying that it is comes across as condescending.

Comment: Sure thing! I suggested creating a 'major_array' and adding 'part_result' in that array on each iteration of loop. This way if your loop iterates 10 times, you will then have 10 arrays added in your 'major_array'. And finally the array is returned when the for loop finishes. :)

Comment: I highly appreciate your suggestion @RagingRoosevelt :) I'm getting familiar with the norms here.

Comment: =D  Keep up the good work.  This site is nothing if there aren't people doing their best to answer questions.

Comment: This was exactly, what I was looking for. And thanks for adding explanation.

Comment: Glad I could help @Viktoria :)

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaJaved Please edit your explanation into your answer. Removing the request for upvotes would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Done @jhpratt :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
def readTXT():
    with open('dataset/sometext.txt') as lines:
        all_lists = []
        for line in lines:
            all_lists.append([int(cell) for cell in line.split()])
        return all_lists
```

Note that the return statement is outside of the loop. You get only one list because you return inside the loop.

For a more advanced user, this solution is a shorter and more efficient but at the cost of being a little hard to understand:

```
def readTXT():
    with open('dataset/sometext.txt') as lines:
        return [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in lines]
```